# D3 TypeError when using URL to reference mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Working on learning D3, I'm able to get a version of the following code to work locally (that is pointing to the d3.vs3.js locally). When I change the URL to http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js I get the following error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data.forEach') in line 49, the line after opening the data2.tsv file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script>
// modification to use URL reference to D3 
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"
            );

// Get the data
d3.tsv("data/data.tsv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close; 
    });
    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
    svg.append("path")      // Add the valueline path.
        .attr("d", valueline(data));
    svg.append("g")         // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    svg.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
});  
</script>
</body>
```

I plan to use D3 in websites so figuring this out seems very crucial. Thanks in advance.
Francis

Answer (score 1):

Use this script tag to load d3 instead of the one you're using:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Tried that and got this error: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'e.length')"

Comment: That's odd because it works here with made up data: http://jsfiddle.net/fsN7W/   Are you sure you're data file exists and has a valid format?

Comment: The file was there, but I used an incomplete name in the code. Whew!